# Php and PDO - fetching data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

can someone please tell me why the following does not work:

```
$result = $this->db->prepare("SELECT high,low FROM data where symbol=:symbol and date1 <= :date1 order by date1 desc LIMIT :limit1");
    $result->bindParam(':symbol', $total_pairs, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result->bindParam(':date1', $date1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result->bindParam(':limit1', $period, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $result->execute();

    $data = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


   var_export($data["high"]);
```

this gives me error:

```
 Undefined index: high
```

I am trying to get both columns and fetch the results in array.

Comment: Why don't you try to use `var_export( $data )` to see what you're getting?

Comment: As error says, there is no index called high. $data should be an array that contain as many associative arrays as rows fetched on the query.

Comment: Its should be `$data[0]["high"]`. Just increment the first index.

Comment: @OrlandoLeite that doesn't help as you can see I am already doing that. I do get an associate array but still not able to reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $data array contains multiple associative arrays (one for each record returned). If you want just the values for high for each record in one array and just the values for low in another the result set, you could do:

```
<?php

$high = array_column($data, 'high');
$low = array_column($data, 'low');

?>
```

Comment: thanks so much for this... i never knew the array_column function before!!! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();

/* Exercise PDOStatement::fetch styles */
print("PDO::FETCH_ASSOC: ");
print("Return next row as an array indexed by column name\n");
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
print("\n");

print("PDO::FETCH_BOTH: ");
print("Return next row as an array indexed by both column name and number\n");
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
print_r($result);
print("\n");

print("PDO::FETCH_LAZY: ");
print("Return next row as an anonymous object with column names as properties\n");
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);
print_r($result);
print("\n");

print("PDO::FETCH_OBJ: ");
print("Return next row as an anonymous object with column names as properties\n");
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
print $result->name;
print("\n");
?>
```

It can help you to understand better.This code is taken from php.net site